# Поддерживают ли новые версии PHP HTTP методы нативно?

Tags: php, http

Поддерживают ли новые версии PHP HTTP методы нативно?

Comment: Эээ, что?........

Comment: @AlexeyTen Но к сожалению в PHP нет $_PUT и $_DELETE, в отличии от $_GET и $_POST. Вот способ ... -X [METHOD] определяет HTTP метод.
Это со статьи на хабре. https://habr.com/ru/post/46032/ она 2008 года. Но так же я читал, статью 2017 года. Где было указано на то  что php не поддерживает HTTP методы.

Comment: веренее поддерживает только $POST $GET. А все остальное пишите руками

Comment: PHP - это язык. HTTP - это протокол. Веб-сервер через FastCGI отдает то, что пришло из браузера, в PHP. PHP разбирает запрос (он в виде текста), инициализирует _SERVER, _GET, _REQUEST и прочее. Какой метод был вызван - можно посмотреть через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. Более PHP о HTTP методах не знает ничего.

Comment: @TotalPusher Ответь на вопрос, я тебе плюс поставлю. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Интересно, что вы хотели видеть в $_DELETE :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen я никого не хочу оскорблять, но я думаю. Стоит посмотреть как с этим же методом справляются .net или nodejs.

Comment: Не знаю как в .net, а в nodejs даже для разбора обычного post надо библиотеку или самому писать код. А параметры из урла у вас и в php всегда в $_GET есть

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP - это язык, HTTP - это протокол.

Веб-сервер через FastCGI отдает то, что пришло из браузера, в PHP. PHP разбирает запрос (он в виде текста), инициализирует `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` и прочее. Какой метод был вызван - можно посмотреть через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Более PHP о HTTP методах не знает ничего. Более того, в запросе можно отправить вообще любое название в качестве HTTP метода.

Также есть ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete)